# Can brandId be retrieved for an envelope using REST API?

Tags: docusignapi

We are using the API to retrieve data from envelopes, mainly text tabs, but one of the fields we need is the brand.  I've seen where brandId can be set when creating an envelope but is this data available when doing a GET on an envelope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to retrieve **brandId** for an existing Envelope, and there is no mention of this possibility in the DocuSign REST API Guide.

A work-around would be to use a "***Custom Envelope Field***" (type = Text) to store **brandId** as a piece of metadata associated with the Envelope when the Envelope is created. For example, to set a (text) custom Envelope field in the **Create Envelope** API request to store the Brand Id, you could simply include this structure as part of the Create Envelope API request:

```
"customFields":{ 
     "textCustomFields":[ 
         { 
             "name":"envBrandId", 
             "required":"false", 
             "show":"false", 
             "value":"XXXX-XX-XXXX-XX-XXXX" 
         } 
     ] 
 }
```

See the DocuSign REST API Guide (https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/rest-api-guide-v2.pdf) for more details.

Then, once the Envelope has been created, you can retrieve the value(s) of Custom Envelope Field(s) by using this request:

```
GET /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/custom_fields
```

Once again, the REST API Guide contains details about this operation.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Since we want to keep the number of API calls down we might use a text tab instead of a custom field since we are already getting recipient tabs and aren't calling custom fields currently.

Comment: Sure, that'll work.  FYI- you can "hide" the value of a text tab (i.e., make it so that the text is not visible in the document), by setting it's Font Color to match the color of the page background.  For example, if the page is white, set the Font Color of the text tab to white -- and it won't be visible in the document. Be mindful of where you place the tag in the document though -- because even though the text won't be visible if its font color matches the page, it will still take up as much space as that text requires -- potentially covering-up/overlaying other content in the document.